# gtk. how can i get widget by id?

Tags: c, unix, callback, gtk, widget

gtk define IO callback as bool func(gtkchannel, GIOCondition,GPointer userdata)

the problem is that I want to send 2 arguments as a user_data: widget and a pointer that will keep my errors form the callback. I know that I can send struct but I want to check if there is another way to do it. 
is there a way to edit the type of the callback?
is there a way to get the widget address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a struct, or make your own class and pass that. Alternatively, use GTK from Python or Vala. Passing data to callbacks is much easier in those languages.

Comment: Object can be passed only if the programs is in C++. But the tag is "C".

Comment: Not true. The whole point of GObject, which underlies GTK, is object-oriented programming in C.

Comment: Yes, but all objects in GTK are implemented as structures. OOP in GTK in C is based on principles of ordinary procedural programming.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, nobody calls GObject classes "structs" just because they're implemented in C.

Comment: Well, in this context to say "send pointer to structure to functioN" and to say "pointer to class" is essentially THE SAME. Two names for one thing )))

Answer (score 0):

I seem that sending a pointer to structure is a valid and the best way. I always do so. 
And I guess it is impossible to change callback function signature but rewriting and recompilng libgtk )))